# Make single-instance item editable in admin panel

Tags: django, django-admin

I have page with some items list and general description;
all of which should be accessible through admin panel.

Maybe I could create model like this:

```
class MyPage(models.Model):  
    general_desc = models.TextField()  

class Items(models.Model):
    Page = models.ForeignKey(MyPage)
    description = models.TextField()
    image = ImageField()
```

create one MyPage record, and then somehow make add/remove actions for MyPage inaccessible in admin panel?

Or thehe is a smarter way?

Comment: Have you considered use the django permissions?

Comment: Permissions could do the job, thanks for hint.